# No startup dropdown nor configuration drop down menu when opening folder with CMakeLists

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

i'm trying to use the cmake integration in visual studio 2017. Msvc detects the CMakeLists.txt, run cmake properly on it (I can build and run), but I dont have the  drop down menus to change my configuration and start debugging.

[image]

Image taken from msdn blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/

Am I missing something? (The toolbar is enable and the buttons are checked)

Comment: Are you saying that in Visual Studio creating a new cmake example project doesn't work for you?  When you create this project you  should see some messages in the output window that it is creating and configuring the project and populate the drop down list like in the picture.  I'm asking because I wasn't sure what created the CMakeLists.txt file in the first place.

Comment: If I open a folder with an existing CMakeLists.txt or create a new Cmake project. I have the message in the output window. I just dont have the dropdown boxes

Comment: I recall that this worked for me without having to do anything special.  I did notice that Visual Studio generated a CMakeLists.json file that contains all the configurations available in the dropdown list.  It generated that file at the same time it created an example project.

Comment: Isnt it CMakeSettings.json instead of CMakeLists.json. If thats the case, it didnt generate it, and if I add it manually, I cant even build anymore. I have raised an issue on msdn (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/398570/no-configuration-when-opening-folder-with-cmakelis.html)